# Why can you make a lambda referencing an instance method by using a class reference?

Tags: java, lambda

```
String[] foo = {"one","two", "three"};
Arrays.sort(foo, (a,b) -> a.compareTo(b));
```

And

```
String[] foo = {"one","two", "three"};
Arrays.sort(foo, String::compareTo);
```

are equivalent.

Why can I reference `compareTo` via `String` when `compareTo` is an instance method?

Comment: [Reference to an Instance Method of an Arbitrary Object of a Particular Type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html)

Comment: Because that's how Java handles method references: by adding the receiver as the first argument of the resulting lambda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think of this example

```
Function<String, String> func;  

func = string -> string.toUpperCase();

func = String::toUpperCase;
```

Think of an instance method as a static method with an extra `this` parameter, for the purpose of deducing method reference.

```
    static String toUpperCase(String this)
```